# I have a dataframe that I am able to see in Jupiter Notebook using df.display(), when I write it to excel, the excel output has only 1 column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

## I need to group the data by the following columns and get the most recent date for answers

```py
df_Q = df.groupby(['question', 'user_id', 'options', 'answer'])
df_Date = df_Q.agg(Recent_Date=('datetime', np.max))
```

Comment: Please clarify your question.  Are you trying to write `df_Date` to Excel?  Please show the code you use to write to Excel and also the output you are getting (in pandas and in Excel) and the output you want.  You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67779632/edit) the question.

Answer (score 0):

I would presume that this is because your dataframe only has one column, as the rest have been converted to "multiindex row-axis labels" by the groupby + agg.

Try adding:

```
df_Date = df_Date.reset_index()
```

Before the export to Excel.

Beware that you might get more than one answer per person per question as you are including "answer" in your groupby. I would presume, depending on your goal, that grouping by "user_id" and "question" might suffice.